# Counterexample to show that the change of variables for integral does not hold

Tags: analysis

Give a Counterexample to show that the change of variables formula does not hold if $g$ is not one-to-one even though $Jg(x) \neq 0$ where $Jg$ is Jacobian Matrix. 
[Hint: Take $f = 1$ and $g(x,y) = (e^x\text{cos}\;y\;,\; e^x\text{sin}\;y$)]

---

It seems pretty easy, but treaky for me. Anybody helps?

Answer (score 0):

If you've seen some generalizations of the change of variables theorem (say, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376728/image-of-a-set-of-zero-measure-has-zero-measure) result), you know that in order to take advantage of $g$'s lack of injectivity you mustn't let there be a zero-measure set such that the restriction of $g$ to its complement is injective.

So, to utilize the hint, pick a domain 'large' enough for $g$ to be 'properly' many-to-one. The rest should follow.