# Smooth image of a null set has measure zero

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Currently I'm looking at the proof of Sard's theorem given in John Milnor's "Topology from the differentiable viewpoint". I'm a bit confused about a remark on the case where the dimension of the target space is strictly larger than the dimension of the initial space.

Let $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth map, where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is open and $m<n$. In this case it is clear that set of critical points of $f$ is just $U$ and here, Sard's theorem simply states that $f(U)$ has measure zero. Milnor says that this is an obvious fact, however, as I'm a bit rusty in measure theory, I wasn't able to proof this.
I also wonder whether the same is true if $f$ is just continuous.

Let me restate the question:

**Let $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be smooth/continuous, where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is open and $m<n$. Does $f(U)$ have Lebesgue measure zero?**

I found a few partial answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376728/image-of-a-set-of-zero-measure-has-zero-measure) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59105/is-the-image-of-a-null-set-under-a-differentiable-map-always-null). But while the first post is not general enough the second one is too general and I think in the case of a smooth map the proof should be quite elementary.

Thank you for any help

Comment: The answer is no in the continous case -- look for 'Peano curves'. In the smooth case the answer is yes, since f is locally Lipshitz (with Lipshitz constant estimated by $2df$, say) and it can be linearly approximated by a map with image in a lower dimensional subspace. With this knowledge you can, e.g., show that, for given $\varepsilon>0$ the image of small cubes of edge length $a$ under $f$ is contained in a rectangular set which has volume $(2|df|a)^n \times \varepsilon^{m -n}\times C$.

Comment: (Sorry, I mixed up $n$ and $m$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment by Thomas is exactly right (the locally-Lipschitz property is what one normally uses here), but I'll add an argument for the smooth case. By exhausting $U$ with compactly contained subdomains, we reduce to the case when the derivative $Df$ is bounded, say $\|Df\|\le M$. Fix $\epsilon>0$. For each point $x\in U$ there is $r=r_x>0$ such that $$|f(y)-Df(x)(y-x)|\le \epsilon |y-x|\quad\text{ whenever } \ |y-x|<r$$ The image of the ball $B(x,r)$ under the linear map $Df(x)$ is contained in the intersection of an $m$-dimensional affine subspace with $B(f(x),Mr)$. By (1), the image of $B(x,r)$ under $f$ is contained in $(\epsilon  r)$-neighborhood of said intersection, which is (more or less)  its product with an $(n-m)$-dimensional ball of radius $\epsilon$.  Therefore, the $n$-dimensional measure of $f(B(x,r))$ is at most $Cr^m\epsilon^{n-m}$.

Applying [Vitali's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_covering_lemma) to the cover of $U$ by $B(x,r_x/5)$ we get a  cover of $U$ by $B(x_i,r_{x_i})$ such that $B(x_i,r_{x_i}/5)$ are disjoint. Hence, the Lebesgue measure of $f(U)$ is at most 
$$
C\epsilon^{n-m} \sum_i r_i^m \le   C  \epsilon^{n-m} 5^m \operatorname{vol}_m U
$$
Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, the conclusion follows.

Comment: copied from: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59105/is-the-image-of-a-null-set-under-a-differentiable-map-always-null

Comment: In the case where $f \in L^{p}(U)$ is it true that  $f^{-1}(\{c\})$ has null measure ?